# Permissões arquivo AndroidManifest.xml

Tags: android, android-manifest

Ao realizar a instalação do *app* pelo Google Play, o *app* emite a msg "App Parou" ai tenho que ir em configurações->Aplicativos->APP e dar as permissões manualmente.

Segue as permissões que necessito e estão no arquivo AndroidManifest.xml

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_WIFI_STATE"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CALL_PHONE"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.VIBRATE"/>
```

Como resolver este problema?

Answer (score 3):

A partir do [Android Marshmallow](https://www.android.com/intl/pt-BR_br/versions/marshmallow-6-0/), API 23, os usuários concedem permissões a aplicativos enquanto eles estão em execução, não quando eles são instalados.

> Essa abordagem otimiza o processo de instalação de aplicativos, pois o
>   usuário não precisa conceder permissões ao instalar ou atualizar o
>   aplicativo.

Além desta questão, também estabelece ao usuário mais controle sobre os recursos do aplicativo. Por exemplo, um usuário poderia optar por permitir que um aplicativo de câmera tenha acesso à câmera, mas não à localização do dispositivo. O usuário pode revogar as permissões a qualquer momento na tela de configurações da aplicação.

Como é mostrado no momento em que concede a permissão:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Confira aqui na documentação sobre [solicitação de permissões em tempo de execução](https://developer.android.com/training/permissions/requesting.html?hl=pt-br)

O código a seguir verifica se o aplicativo tem a permissão para ler os contatos do usuário e solicita a permissão, se necessário:

```
if (ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(thisActivity,
                Manifest.permission.READ_CONTACTS)
        != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {

    if (ActivityCompat.shouldShowRequestPermissionRationale(thisActivity,
            Manifest.permission.READ_CONTACTS)) {

    } else {


        ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(thisActivity,
                new String[]{Manifest.permission.READ_CONTACTS},
                MY_PERMISSIONS_REQUEST_READ_CONTACTS);
    }
}
```